# How to style xml file? from xml to html using xslt and style that html using css

Tags: css, xml, xslt

Ok that a very short question but here I will explain what I want to do.

Suppose I have xml file with various data 
lets say I have an element there called cd which have child elements like genre, composer, number of_songs and so on.

So I can use XSLT to generate a html file and display 
composer and genre but I will hide the numberof_songs and other tags

First question:
now how to use css to style that generated html file.

Second question:
how can I write a program in php to read that original xml not the generated html one, file to do some computation.

Please ask if you want more explanation.
Thank you

Comment: There are too many and too broad questions here. One is about styling an HTML page with CSS. The question in the title is different: about styling XML (which is quite possible without any conversion to HTML). And the question about PHP is yet another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, simply include the css (or a reference to it), in the html source generated by your XSLT. I do this all the time.

Second question- if the URL is to an XML document that has your XSLT associated as a stylesheet using `<?xsl-stylesheet..` then any code reading that URL will get the original XML document, and can do whatever they want with it. This is actually a very good way of having a web page both human and machine readable.

Comment: Thank you, Its all working for now.